# PostgreSQL, FULL OUTER JOIN on multiple tables (all "combinations")

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm very new to PostgrSQL and SQL in general. I'm trying to use the FULL OUTER JOIN function to join 11 tables based on respective 11 columns. Below you can find my code:

```
SELECT * FROM _0_general_view
FULL OUTER JOIN _1_foundation_view
ON _0_general_view.concatenate_0_general = _1_foundation_view.concatenate_1_foundation
FULL OUTER JOIN _1_plinth_view
ON _0_general_view.concatenate_0_general = _1_plinth_view.concatenate_1_plinth
FULL OUTER JOIN _1_rc_beams_columns_view
ON _0_general_view.concatenate_0_general = _1_rc_beams_columns_view.concatenate_1_rc_beams_columns
FULL OUTER JOIN _1_vertical_members_view
ON _0_general_view.concatenate_0_general = _1_vertical_members_view.concatenate_1_vertical_members
FULL OUTER JOIN _2_floor_view
ON _0_general_view.concatenate_0_general = _2_floor_view.concatenate_2_floor
FULL OUTER JOIN _2_horizontal_bands_view
ON _0_general_view.concatenate_0_general = _2_horizontal_bands_view.concatenate_2_horizontal_bands
FULL OUTER JOIN _2_rc_beams_columns_view
ON _0_general_view.concatenate_0_general = _2_rc_beams_columns_view.concatenate_2_rc_beams_columns
FULL OUTER JOIN _2_vertical_members_view
ON _0_general_view.concatenate_0_general = _2_vertical_members_view.concatenate_2_vertical_members
FULL OUTER JOIN _2_walls_view
ON _0_general_view.concatenate_0_general = _2_walls_view.concatenate_2_walls
FULL OUTER JOIN _3_roof_view
ON _0_general_view.concatenate_0_general = _3_roof_view.concatenate_3_roof
;
```

In the code above, I'm assuming that my tables are structures as below:

**Table 1** (_0_general_view)

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║   col_1  ║  col_2  ║  col_3  ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║     a    ║ 3.5046  ║   Jan   ║
║     b    ║ 3.7383  ║   Mar   ║
║     c    ║ 3.9719  ║   Jul   ║
║     d    ║ 6.1915  ║   Feb   ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

**Table 2** (_1_plinth_view)

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║   col_4  ║  col_5  ║  col_6  ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║     a    ║ 2.8846  ║   Dec   ║
║     d    ║ 5.2244  ║   Aug   ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

**Table n** (_3_xxxx_view)

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║   col_7  ║  col_8  ║  col_9  ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║     b    ║ 1.2365  ║   May   ║
║     c    ║ 2.5432  ║   Sep   ║
║     d    ║ 8.1515  ║   Oct   ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

In other words, I'm assuming that col_1 (named `concatenate_0_general` in the first table/view, named `_0_general_view`) contains all the records I need to join, but what if this is not true?

I can't find a way to take into account all the possible combinations among my 11 tables. Is it possible in some way?

And if so, do you think it's going to be a very long process considering that each table has, on average 150 columns, and that the number of rows in each table might be around 10000.

**EDIT:** Probably the we will have to retrive way less records, let's say around 300-400, since we will add a WHERE clause to filter them by date.

Comment: What are you going to do with a 1650 column result with tens of thousands of rows?

Comment: Honestly I was a bit hasty in writing. In the end the rows will be (way, I hope) less since we will have to filter them, with a WHERE I guess, by week or month (we are talking about many house assessments). After filtering, we need to export them to a CSV file and connect the CSV file with an Excel file in order to perform engineering calculations on the data collected.

Comment: Full outer join on such a number of tables and columns is rarely needed, it’s surprising that you would need to retrieve 150x11 columns for all the records... I agree with the previous comment. Explain us what you are tryin to achieve and we might find a better solution.

Comment: Have you considered UNION ALL instead of all those LEFT JOIN's? Add a "type" column.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm right, but UNION ALL implies also the presence of duplicates, if any, isn't it? The idea was using PostgreSQL to join all the tables because using Excel to perform this task seems to be too landy. I'll try to explain better why we have some many tables and also duplicates: each table represents a house structural element (in total 11), each house has different structural element assessable depending on its stage of construction, we have many engineers and each engineer can assess the house multiple times in different days.

Comment: Can you show how those views look like? Single table or complex?

Comment: @dnoeth, what do you mean for "complex"? The joined view/table? By the way, here you can have a look at 3 of these 11 views: https://imgur.com/a/caRAB

Comment: A view might be a simple `select .. from oneTable where some conditions` or `select ... from multi-table-joins where complex- subqueries`

Answer (score 1):

If the `join` columns had the same name, you could use `using`:

```
select . . .
from a join
     b
     on (id) join
     c
     on (id) . . .;
```

In your case, `union all` and aggregation is the best approach -- assuming that you will end up with one row per "id":

```
select id, max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2, max(col3) as col3,
       max(col4) as col4, max(col5) as col5, max(col6) as col6
from ((select concatenate_0_general as id, col1, col2, NULL as col3, NULL as col4, NULL as col5, NULL as col6
       from _0_general_view
      ) union all
      (select concatenate_1_foundation, NULL, NULL, col3, col4, NULL, NULL
       from _1_foundation_view
      ) union all
      (select concatenate_1_plinth, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, col5, col6
       from _1_plinth_view
      )
     ) x
group by id;
```

If neither of these work, then you can construct a full list of ids and use `left join`:

```
select . . .
from ((select concatenate_0_general as id from _0_general_view
      ) union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select concatenate_1_foundation from _1_foundation_view
      ) union
      (select concatenate_1_plinth from _1_plinth_view
      ) union
      . . .
     ) ids left join
     _0_general_view gv
     on gv.concatenate_0_general = ids.id left join
     . . .
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I think this is a bit advanced for me. My join columns have different names but I don't understand the difference between your 2nd and 3rd example. Also I don't get how the union is removing the duplicates.

Comment: The second example uses `union`/`group by` and the third is using `left join`.  They are very different.  The first subquery in the `left join` is bringing together all the "id"s.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this 1st colum is unique (otherwise your result set will explode, no matter if Left or Full join), you can create a list of all existing values first and then Left Join all tables to it:

```
select _0_general_view.*,
   _1_foundation_view.*,
   _1_plinth_view.*
...
from
 (
   select concatenate_0_general as col from _0_general_view
   union 
   select concatenate_1_foundation from _1_foundation_view
   union
   select concatenate_1_plinth from _1_plinth_view
   ...
 ) as dt
left join _0_general_view 
  on col = concatenate_0_general
left join _1_foundation_view
  on col = concatenate_1_foundation
left join _1_plinth_view
  on col = concatenate_1_plinth
...
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, I tried your code and is working well but I cannot understand how it is different from the code I wrote in the first post. When you say that col_1 has to be unique, you mean that cannot be the same of col_4 or col_7?

Comment: @aragornii: In your 1st post you wrote, that you don't know if the 1st column in the 1st table contains all possible values. In that case your 11 FULL must be based on `COALESCE` all 1st columns from all previously joined tables. When you create that list first (using UNION), it's way simpler LEFT joins. Regarding uniqueness: when the 1st column in those views is not unique you will increase the number of rows in your result, e.g. 2 rows with the same value in each table will result in 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2 = 2^11 rows.